# Должны ли названия всех языков писаться с большой буквы?

Tags: орфография

В русском языке языки пишутся с маленькой буквы: английский, немецкий, но почему-то мы пишем English, Russian, C#, Питон. Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-русски правильно писать названия языков со строчной буквы: английский, немецкий.

По-английски правильно писать названия языков с прописной буквы: English, Russian.

Не нужно смешивать правила двух языков. Если написано латиницей, то и русские правила в большинстве случаев неприменимы. Вы же не станете писать местоимение I как i, только исходя из того, что оно упомянуто в учебнике для русскоязычной аудитории?

Что касается C# и "Питона", то это несколько иные языки. Это языки программирования. Поэтому и называются они не прилагательными с существительным, а именами собственными, то есть названиями конкретных программных продуктов. А названия программных продуктов, фирм, торговых марок и т.д. в русском языке пишутся с прописной буквы, как и имена, и названия городов, стран или гор. Тут никакого противоречия нет.